# Changed version code and now expansion file not found

Tags: android, apk, apk-expansion-files

I uploaded my apk to Google Play, but had to upload again because I had an expansion file and of course you can't upload the expansion file on the first try. When I uploaded the apk for a 2nd time I changed the version to 2 and it named my expansion file main.2.com.ssowens.groovebass.obb . Therefore, I adjusted the version in my code and renamed the obb file. Now the file isn't found and I can't for the life of me figure out why. What else do I need to update for a version update?

Here is what I changed:
Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="main.2.com.ssowens.groovebass.obb"
        android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="1.0" >
```

In DownloaderFragment

```
       public static final int MAIN_EXPANSION_FILE_VERSION = 2;
```

Didn't change anything here, but seems to be where it is failing

```
       boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
       for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(getActivity(), 
            xf.mIsMain,  xf.mFileVersion);
        if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+++ fileName +++ " + fileName + " " + xf.mFileSize + " " 
        + " " + xf.mIsMain + " , " + xf.mFileVersion);
        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(getActivity(), fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
            return false;
     }
      return true;
     }
```

Here is what prints out in the log:

```
09-16 17:56:16.045: E/Trace(20344): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-16 17:56:16.138: V/DownloaderFragment(20344): +++ fileName +++ main.2.com.ssowens.groovebass.obb FileSize=> 519953080   xf.mIsMain=> true  xf.mFileVersion=> 2
09-16 17:56:16.138: V/DownloaderFragment(20344): +++ expansionFilesNotDelivered +++
09-16 17:56:16.232: D/LVLDL(20344): Service Bound
09-16 17:56:16.271: D/libEGL(20344): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
09-16 17:56:16.310: D/libEGL(20344): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
09-16 17:56:16.318: D/libEGL(20344): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
09-16 17:56:16.443: D/OpenGLRenderer(20344): Enabling debug mode 0
09-16 17:56:16.802: I/LicenseChecker(20344): Binding to licensing service.
09-16 17:56:17.013: I/LicenseChecker(20344): Calling checkLicense on service for com.ssowens.groovebass
09-16 17:56:17.013: I/LicenseChecker(20344): Start monitoring timeout.
09-16 17:56:17.615: I/LicenseChecker(20344): Received response.
09-16 17:56:17.615: I/LicenseChecker(20344): Clearing timeout.
09-16 17:56:17.623: E/LicenseValidator(20344): Signature verification failed.
```

Here is the name of the file:

main.2.com.ssowens.groovebass.obb

Verified file directory, file size and file name.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem of not able to read the expansion file after i had uploaded to Google Play (On the second upload of APK file with expansion pack to Google Play)

I realize that Google Play will update the expansion file naming from 1 to 2 automatically depending on the package version code. So I added in `PackageInfo` `VersionCode` to `APKExpansionSupport` and the problem is solved.

Example:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
ZipResourceFile zrf =     APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(TravelDoorStartActivity.this, pInfo.versionCode, 0);
```

Hope that this will help the others beginner like me :)

Comment: Google can be a real liar sometimes..

`"First" is emphasized because although the Developer Console allows you to re-use an uploaded expansion file with a new APK, the expansion file's name does not change—it retains the version applied to it when you first uploaded the file.` ([Source](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Filename))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you placed your expansion file name in place of package name

```
package="main.2.com.ssowens.groovebass.obb"
```

I suppose that you should have:

```
package="com.ssowens.groovebass"
```

[Expansion file naming rules](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Filename) are:

```
[main|patch].<expansion-version>.<package-name>.obb
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Must have done a cut and paste late at night. How can you see what it is comparing it with? That would have helped since the file name was displayed correctly in my error message. @luten